# How to make a sharepoint layout page(application page) into site page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, solution-package

[image: Please Click the Link to see the Image]
i deployed a wsp into UAT , since a layout page cannot be home page/landing page
i want to reference a layout application page in a sharepoint site Page(Home Page)

Please Suggest!!!

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because an application page is accessible from any site collection, any site. As it's location in the layouts folder. I suggest you should create a page layout for your home page and than create a page based on that page layout. Than set it as home page.

Comment: Or add a redirect from the home page to the application page. There's lots of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Page Viewer Web Part to display your application page in the home page.